# environment variable lost in web application

Tags: php, python, environment-variables

I wrote a PHP web page which calls a python file, in the python file I called a program "antiword"

antiword depends on $HOME to run, but when running python file in my browser, I found $HOME is not set, so antiword cannot be run.

How do I let my python file recognize $HOME?

I use redhat.

Thanks

Comment: How does a web page "call a python file"?

Comment: php for web, in php a python module is called

Comment: PHP doesn't call Python modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You' re looking for [`putenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php).

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I have hardcoded the path.

Comment: I don't know how this answer relates to your problem. Is it the problem solved because you discovered you hardcoded the path, or is that the solution?